# I want to get input field name jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get the ID number of the `name` in each of the input fields in my form.

For example: `name="SectionNumber[]"`, it should be `name="SectionNumber1"`, `name="SectionNumber2"`, `name="SectionNumber3"` so I could submit them to my database.

I am using this to add `id` to name but it does not work. Please help.

```
 $row.clone().insertBefore($button).attr('name', newId);
```

This is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f8rfap22/

Comment: I thought it should be like $row.clone().insertBefore($button.attr('name', newId));

Comment: Why does all textboxes have same id and name CourseNumber[] ?

Comment: @bharatpatel I changed that and still not working

Answer (score 0):

I check your fiddle, and update some code as like

```
    var row = $row.clone();
        $(row).find("input[type='text']").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('name', newId)
        console.log($(this).attr("name"));
    });
    row.insertBefore($button);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f8rfap22/1/ check this fiddle, what ever you change I done for button not for row, so I changed it. hope it will help you.